# How do I find out and change the value of <input type = "text"> in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I want to find the value of  and want to mask the first 4th of the text field to another character when the length of the text field is 4 or greater.

but I don't know well asp.net skill. help me plz.

here is some html in body tag

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" runat="server" id="input1" name="input1" value="TestText" />
            <input type="button" runat="server" class="btnCnvt" name="btnCnvt" id="btnCnvt" value="convert" onclick="GetValue()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

here is javascript :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetValue()
        {
              // Don't Work!!!(not fount 'value' attribute)
              var str = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: what time you call GetValue function? when btnCnvt clicked?

Comment: In your browser, please `View Source`. Update your question with the HTML that was generated from your code fragment (so we can see what HTML that code resulted in).

Comment: First I'll input some string in the textbox(input1), and click the btnCnvt button!

Answer (score 0):

Your button is from server side, So, javascript function will not fire on `OnClick` event, instead use `OnClientClick` event.